# Youtube Embedded Player: Prevent video from appearing in User's Watch History

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am writing a webapp that integrates with Youtube and plays Videos using the Youtube Embedded Player.
One feature I'm trying to implement involves preventing a Video that is being watched from being added to the User's Watch History. That way they can watch songs related to movies/tv shows/video games without getting assaulted with potentially spoiler containing videos the next time they log into Youtube.

I have been unable to prevent it by sandboxing the iframe the player is in.
It also looks like removing entries from the Watch History has been deprecated as of August 2016 with the Data API.

Is there any way to prevent Youtube from tracking the video being watched?
Thanks!